# Angular - Set a mat-tab-link active after a tab is closed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, tabs, mat-tab

I am trying to create a tabbar that works similarly to the browser tabs. Each tab loads a module.
I am trying with `mat-tab-nav-bar`. Opening a new tab and setting it active as well as switching back and forth between tabs works fine. Closing a tab works and the tab is deleted from the array. Unfortunately, I cannot make the previously opened tab or the tab next to the closed tab active again and load the module. I put the last loaded and active page into the `sessionStorage` and load this page after a reload in the `ngOnInit()` function.

Angular and TypeScript are still new to me and I haven't gained much experience yet.

I have taken this example as a template. I also tried with this example, but I could not load any modules and with mat-tab-nab-bar it worked fine.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzehu6?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-dynamic-example.html

If a tab is to be deleted, the `onRemoveTab()` event is triggered. There I loop over the tabs and as soon as the tab to be deleted is found, I remove it from the Tabs array and set the previous tab in the `FormControler` as Active (or try to set it Active). I also save this tab in the `sessionStorage`.
The result is that only the deleted tab is removed, but the previous tab is not set active and the module is not reloaded.
How can I make this happen? Does anyone have an idea?

Here is my code. Please let me know if you need more information.

tabbar.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="currentTab">
  <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a
      mat-tab-link
      *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let index = index"
      [routerLink]="tab.link"
      routerLinkActive="false"
      #rla="routerLinkActive"
      [active]="rla.isActive"
      (click)="onSelect(tab, index)"
      disableRipple
    >
      {{tab.name}}
      <button 
        mat-icon-button 
        (click)="onRemoveTab(tab.id, index)" 
        [disabled]="tabs.length === 1"
      >
        <mat-icon style="transform: scale(0.8);">close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

tabbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { SidenavRouteInterface } from './data';

@Component({
  selector: 'tabbar',
  templateUrl: './tabbar.component.html', 
})
export class TabbarComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  selected = new FormControl(0);
  tabs: SidenavRouteInterface[] = [];
  sessionKey = 'currentTab';
  previousTab: SidenavRouteInterface | undefined;
  

  onSelect(router: SidenavRouteInterface, index: number) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(this.sessionKey, JSON.stringify(router));
    this.selected.setValue(router.id);
  }

  onRemoveTab(tabId: number, index: number) {
    this.tabs.forEach((tab) => {
      if (tab.id === tabId) {
        this.tabs.splice(index, 1);
        this.selected.setValue(this.previousTab?.id);

        sessionStorage.setItem(this.sessionKey, JSON.stringify(this.previousTab));
      } else {
        this.previousTab = tab;
      }
    });

    return false;
  }
}
```

sidenav-route.model.ts

```
export interface SidenavRouteInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  link: string;
  icon?: string;
}
```

An example of how a tab in the array can look.

```
tabs: SidenavRouteInterface[] = [
  { id: 6, name: 'Document', link: 'document' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Reference', link: 'reference' },
];
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are displaying which tab is active based on the URL, correct? I would expect to see a call to `router.navigate()` somewhere in your `onSelect` and `onRemoveTab` methods

Comment: So simple! That solved my problem. I will post the solution as soon as I finish it. Thank you! @jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.router.navigate([this.previousTab.link])` does the trick.

```
onRemoveTab(tabId: number, index: number) {
  this.tabs.forEach((tab) => {
    if (tab.id === tabId) {
      this.tabs.splice(index, 1);
      this.selected.setValue(this.previousTab?.id);
      this.router.navigate([this.previousTab.link]);

      sessionStorage.setItem(this.sessionKey, JSON.stringify(this.previousTab));
    } else {
      this.previousTab = tab;
    }
  });

  return false;
}
```